# IEnumerable to Object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm a little confused on how exactly this works. I have an `IEnumerable<T>` list that I'm pulling from a stored procedure in a mySQL database.

```
IEnumerable<CheckInVar> CheckInVars = 
    context.Database
           .SqlQuery<CheckInVar>("Call getCheckinVars(\"WEB\")").ToList();
```

Now, do I need to loop through this object to pull out the properties so that I can use them such as this?

```
foreach (var prop in CheckInVars.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(CheckInVars, null));
}
```

Or can I directly work off of that `IEnumerable<CheckInVar>` object, or do I need to convert that to work with it?

```
public class CheckInVar
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Column("ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string VarValue { get; set; }
    public string AccessMethod { get; set; }
    public string Active { get; set; }
    public string DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string DateUpdated { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `CheckInVar`?

Comment: Just reference your CheckInVars class directly, there's absolutely no reason to resort to reflection here: `foreach (var civ in CheckInVars) {...}`

Comment: If I may, you are firing a missile to kill a mosquito :) @Amy is right, you don't have to use reflection

Comment: Ah... Thank you Amy.  I would use reflection to loop through the properties in a nested foreach loop though correct?

Comment: Not sure what SqlQuery returns but if deferred execution is acceptable, you may be able to do away with the ToList or replace with AsEnumerable to save enumerating the result list twice.

Comment: To *loop* over the properties, yes, you can use reflection.  It doesn't matter if its nested or not.  If I may offer some advice, don't worry about reflection until you're comfortable with the language.  It's a more advanced topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

If you, for some reason, wish to access each collection (IEnumerable) item's properties via reflection, then you will have to loop through the IEnumerable and process each item in turn.

Using your example:

```
foreach(var checkInVar in CheckInVars)
{
    foreach(var prop in checkInVar.GetType().GetProperties())
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(checkInVar)); 
    }
}
```

As others have mentioned though, is reflection really necessary? Can you not access the properties directly?

I'm guessing you may be using reflection to allow changes to the CheckInVar type without having to change your processing code.

Answer (score 2):

Try using foreach:

```
IEnumerable<CheckInVar> CheckInVars = context.Database.SqlQuery<CheckInVar>(
    "Call getCheckinVars(\"WEB\")").ToList();

foreach(CheckInVar item in CheckInVars)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ID: " + item.ID.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Code: " + item.Code);
    Console.WriteLine("VarValue: " + item.VarValue);
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer to the question, "Do I need to loop through this object" the answer is yes. But as explained by Amy there is a better way.

Remenber that CheckInVars may be composed of none or many Checkinvar. I